# How do I initialize an API on PHP

Tags: php

I'm completely new to webapps and I've been trying to include this API (https://github.com/kronusme/dota2-api) to explore and learn.

However, I'm clueless on what to do at this segment https://github.com/kronusme/dota2-api#install

Initialize `Dota2-Api` like this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dota2Api\Api;

Api::init('YOUR_API_KEY', array('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db_name', 'table_prefix_'));"
```

I'm guessing I'm supposed to add a code into a `.php` file and execute it but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Running on an `ubuntu aws` with `mysql` all set up.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a .php file?

Comment: Did you know how to use `PHP` in general?

Comment: In modern PHP, the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` part is something you should already invoke once, usually when you start processing a request. If you've never seen that before, read up on Composer. The rest of that snippet is just something you have to run at any point when you're processing a request, but before you do anything else with the `Dota2Api\Api` class. It simply configures the class. It's not very clear what you're asking, though.

Comment: The github project you link is a **library**, not a standalone application for end users. You simply cannot install and use it as if it was Adobe Reader or Microsoft Word.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies.  
  
@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  
@spirit  
I've barely any knowledge with php but do have java/c knowledge.
I tried putting it into a `test.php` file in `/home/ubuntu/` and it didn't return any error when i did `php test.php` on the terminal

Comment: @Rhymoid Thank you for the clear explaination, was quite lost till I read your reply. So in the .php files that does the requests I have to add those lines at the top correct?
I wasn't sure what to ask either as I did not understand what I'm supposed to do with those lines.

Comment: Well, PHP usually **processes** incoming HTTP requests, that's what it's originally made for. Since you run it as a standalone script (instead of under a web server), read "processing a request" just as "running the script". The first thing any modern PHP script does is to install the autoloader; if you don't know PHP that well, it's *really advisable to learn more about PHP* itself. If you don't understand its class system (quite different from Java and C, which separate compilation and execution, while PHP doesn't), understanding what you're doing with that autoloader isn't going to be easy.